# A way to change facebook like and share buttons text

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-social-plugins

I put a facebook [like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) in my website so people can like my fb page from there.
Is there any way to change the text that is displayed near the button? 
Right now it's "some-friend, some-other-friend and 30,000 people like this"

I want to change "this" to my website's name..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, that´s not possible at all. You can only choose between the options from the generator. It is not allowed to change the appearance in any other way either. But you can use another version of it ("button", for example) and write any text you like NEXT to it.

Comment: But I can't remove "this" so it will be like "some-friend, some-other-friend and 30,000 people like this my-sites-name"

Comment: the "button" version does not have that text, that´s what i meant